# View doesn't show 2nd time when switching views?

Tags: ios, view, switch-statement

In my app when I am switching views with an animation using UIView animations, it works fine the first time when I switch views because the view slides properly into place and everything works. But if I switch back to my original view and then go BACK to the new view, it does not show anything, the view is black but I know my method is getting called.

My code is below, but does anyone see anything that is wrong?

```
-(void)changeView2ToView3 {
    [view2.view.superview addSubview:view3.view];
    [view3.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, kHeight, kWidth, kHeight)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 
                     animations:^{
                         [view3.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kWidth, kHeight)];  
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [view2.view removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

kHeight and kWidth are the height and width of the screen and they are never 0 or nil.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first time, view2.view's superview must be nil. So you have to set a variable for saving the superview.

```
[view2.view removeFromSuperview];
// now view2.view.superview == nil;
```

Comment: Can you show me how to properly set the superview to an ivar? Then I will accept and up vote your answer!

Comment: Btw it is not nil, I just proved that with NSLogs!